# Typescript interface are not overloading / merging subsequent interface fields

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-models

I know that interfaces in typescript allow us to merge different types. When i tried to do so, i am getting error while transpiling the script.

Here is my buggy interface

```js
export interface StoreConfig extends Document, TimeStamps {
  type: 'webhook'
  metadata: {
    endpoint: string
    method: HttpMethod
    secret: string
    event: string | string[]
  }
}

export interface StoreConfig extends Document, TimeStamps {
  type: 'buylink'
  metadata: {
    prodId: string
    key: string
    expire: Date
  }
}

export interface StoreConfig extends Document, TimeStamps {
  type: 'paymentmethod'
  metadata: {
    apiKey: string
    mode: string
    whsecret: string
  }
}
```

I am getting this error on transpiling ts script

```
Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'type' must be of type '"webhook"', but here has type '"buylink"'.
```

PS: I have seen many libraries (for example: nodemailer, inquirer) are loading typings based on some flag or condition.

Comment: Name the interfaces differently and then `export type StoreConfig =  Interface1 | Interface2 | Interface3;`

Comment: This is expected behavior. _Non-function members of the interfaces should be unique. If they are not unique, they must be of the same type. The compiler will issue an error if the interfaces both declare a non-function member of the same name, but of different types._ https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/**
 * Simplified example
 */

export interface StoreConfig extends Document {
    type: 'webhook'

}

export interface StoreConfig extends Document {
    type: 'buylink'

}

export interface StoreConfig extends Document {
    type: 'paymentmethod'
}

/**
 * This is how it works
 * 1) 
 */

export interface A {
    type: 'buylink'

}

export interface A {
    payload: number
}

type O = keyof A // type | payload

/**
 * Because you can't do smth like that
 */

type CustomType = 'buylink' & 'webhook' // never

/**
 * Above type is never because it is irrepresentable
 * Please treat merging as & operator on high level
 */
```

[Demo1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhlBLAtgBwDbwGbwKYBNLYAeAhiqtlCMOOEcgPYBOALpPAHbPaMbEDG2OMybYAwvXZYA5gUJd2uAM6QAIvT4BXRNk6QA3lEhHmAT2TYAXJADkAd2wAjABb16Aa2s0AvjTpNWHFw8-IKwwoxiEtKy8kqq6lo6rAZGxmaWNg4aJujsHpDAwASMjEwANJDEynTYfFy43jSgENCQACpO8MpdkC62bKy2TG6KlJAAjACUkJTUtIQMLGyc3LwCkACC%20oZp5lbWWTkcHo3ziwErwetbKanIxDn0xLhW7FoO3OA%204KbmkADykAAvJA3NgTPQMJsCkVfoIAD6Qe6PZ5NMBjABCtWIGkUgghGkgfGI7GsrFw9EgikQzCckHQYMgtOIzFmNDhkFEuOEiDa6WBmWyuXyADIbPZnK58oVIOxsAA3T7gZpjDYOeiKpn8npyxWMSAfYm4wTwALdErYZARPGcYgOchjAAK5CqgmYERZkG0jCkHBkVUgYvo5kYLKYkAkvXgUjp5EVqFmQA)

What you need to do is to make a union type. Just like @ritaj wrote in his comment:

```js
export interface StoreConfig1 extends Document {
    type: 'webhook'

}

export interface StoreConfig2 extends Document {
    type: 'buylink'

}

export interface StoreConfig3 extends Document {
    type: 'paymentmethod'
}

type StoreConfig = StoreConfig1 | StoreConfig2 | StoreConfig3
```

[Demo2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhlBLAtgBwDbwGbwKYBNLYAeAhiqtlCMOOEcgPYBOALpPAHbPaMbEDG2OMybYAwvXZYA5gEYChLu1wBnSABF6fAK6JsnSAG8okE8wCeybAC5IAcgDu2AEYALevQDWtmgF8adJlYOLh5%20QVhhRjEJaQAmeUUVdU0dPVYjE1MLazsnLTN0di9ff0IGFjZObl4BIRFxSXgpAGYEvSSNbV19DMzzSxtbZGIzbuZdZjdcbz9wfvDI6MapSABeOqiG6TkAHw2luMg9iPqYpuagA)

Comment: When i am doing this I am getting `Type 'StoreConfig' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'.` on mongoose model function. This is my code in another file `model<StoreConfig>(Model.StoreConfiguration, schema)`

Comment: @tbhaxor sorry, I'm not aware about mongoose context here

Comment: also when I am adding new field `metadata` with each interface (which is again an interface), I am only seeing the common fields (only those which have same type and name in all three main StoreConfig interfaces)


See this loom video for example, https://www.loom.com/share/2df3da5a9afc4462838bf14d66daceb9

Comment: Share your STORE_CONFIG class.
You need to do small refactor, because STORE CONFIG instance should already have all properties defined

Comment: I have created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/tbhaxor/f36aa9b02e63eb552b5a99eb05357e9c)

Comment: I have a question, I usually have to provide the type with `as` keyword when I am using union types. So here also when I see the typings are being guessed by vscode.

Since @Aleksey said type overloading is only supported by the functions or methods. So i think the issue is resolved. If I am wrong anywhere please correct me

Comment: Small tip: there are only few cases when you need to use `as` operator. So my rule of thumb (90%): if you use `as`, you probably did smth wrong

Comment: @tbhaxor please share gist with whole your code, I will try to help

Comment: I have included instructions, loom video and buggy code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tbhaxor/f09937ba8224049cb06780567ded04d1). Since this code is from a product, i can't share the whole code base. So I just picked the buggy code.

Comment: @tbhaxor You need just create builder function.
Please see the demo https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRmmAGEIl0EBzARjlFSQBMBnOAEQmwFcBbYFHADeAKDji4MAJ5hgALjgByAO7AARgAsIEANaKRIgL4HQkWIhRosuAkSilylKgCZ6IRqw5c+A+KImSMvJKatxSADbIegbGIqbQ8MioGDh4hMRkFNQAzG4ebJw8-IL+EtKyCopgmFLFMPwwWkz6seVpdg5ZVHAAvLYZjtR0AD799plOrqPp44NU2QbY5CzwoQjhTGi9cAAUS11yM51OAJQ9AHyl4vsrcCsDXdtIwMoEACoA8gBKAKIA+iQPgA5ABiAEkAOI7E4AbjEEnsMG4UCQwnhAXEADpsfdZl0ADTojHYzH7JxE4zGIA

Comment: that what i was wondering to overload builder function in order to fix this issue